# Pandas: Change column values based on dictionary keeping rows with no match

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have a data frame with Country names and would like to modify some of the values based on a dictionary:

```
enDict = {
    "Republic of Korea": "South Korea",
    "United States of America": "United States",
    "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom",
    "China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region": "Hong Kong"
}
```

I'm able to create a 'mask' with:

```
mask = (energy['Country'].isin(enDict))
```

However, I'd like to apply that mask on the 'Country' column only when 'True' not to modify the values not contained in the dictionary, i.e. keeping the values of the rows with no match.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we can use [Series.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) method:

```
energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].replace(enDict, regex=True)
```

Comment: @piRSquared, ha-ha :-D Thank you!

Comment: Fixed!  Thank you guys for the help!

Comment: Done. The platform makes you wait for ~15min to accept the answer.